# How do I reuse a T::Struct structure in another T::Struct

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have the following:

```
class Coordinate < T::Struct
  const :x, Integer
  const :y, Integer
end

class ThreeDCoordinate < T::Struct
  const :x, Integer
  const :y, Integer
  const :z, Integer
end
```

What I want is to have my `ThreeDCoordinate` inherit `x` and `y` of `Coordinate` so I don't have to rewrite them in `ThreeDCoordinate`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Apart from your `T::Struct` problem: don't use inheritance just because your classes share some attributes.

Comment: I'm confused why I wouldn't want to use inheritance if my struct shares all of the attributes of another structs. It will just be adding additional attributes so it seems like the perfect reason to use it?

Comment: If you have a method to calculate the distance between two `Coordinate` instances, would it still work if you pass two `ThreeDCoordinate` instances instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this, using `T::InexactStruct`, but you will have to give up being able to strongly type the initializer of your structs:

```rb
# typed: true

class Coordinate < T::InexactStruct
  const :x, Integer
  const :y, Integer
end

class ThreeDCoordinate < Coordinate
  const :z, Integer
end


coord = Coordinate.new(x: 2, y: 3)
T.reveal_type(coord.x)
T.reveal_type(coord.y)

threeD = ThreeDCoordinate.new(x: 2, y: 3, z: 4)
T.reveal_type(threeD.x)
T.reveal_type(threeD.y)
T.reveal_type(threeD.z)

# Note that the constructors are not typed anymore:
Coordinate.new(x: "foo", y: :bar) # This should fail but doesn't
```

[Sorbet Playground Link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Aclass%20Coordinate%20%3C%20T%3A%3AInexactStruct%0A%20%20const%20%3Ax%2C%20Integer%0A%20%20const%20%3Ay%2C%20Integer%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20ThreeDCoordinate%20%3C%20Coordinate%0A%20%20const%20%3Az%2C%20Integer%0Aend%0A%0A%0Acoord%20%3D%20Coordinate.new%28x%3A%202%2C%20y%3A%203%29%0AT.reveal_type%28coord.x%29%0AT.reveal_type%28coord.y%29%0A%0AthreeD%20%3D%20ThreeDCoordinate.new%28x%3A%202%2C%20y%3A%203%2C%20z%3A%204%29%0AT.reveal_type%28threeD.x%29%0AT.reveal_type%28threeD.y%29%0AT.reveal_type%28threeD.z%29%0A%0A%23%20Note%20that%20the%20constructors%20are%20not%20typed%20anymore%3A%0ACoordinate.new%28x%3A%20%22foo%22%2C%20y%3A%20%3Abar%29%20%23%20This%20should%20fail%20but%20doesn%27t)

The problem with `T::Struct` and subclassing is that Sorbet creates an initializer for your struct that takes into account all of its declared fields. So for `Coordinate` the initializer has the signature `params(x: Integer, y: Integer).void` but for `ThreeDCoordinate` it has the signature `params(x: Integer, y: Integer, z: Integer).void`. Now these signatures are not compatible with each other, so Sorbet does not allow you to subclass one from the other.

`T::InexactStruct` allows you to give up the strong typing in the constructor and trade it in for being able to do inheritance on typed structs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Sorbet does not support exactly the feature that you asked.

However, I am using interfaces to achieve similar typing goals:

```rb
module Coordinate
  extend T::Helpers
  extend T::Sig

  interface!

  sig { abstract.returns(Integer) }
  def x; end

  sig { abstract.returns(Integer) }
  def y; end
end

module ThreeCoordinate
  extend T::Helpers
  extend T::Sig

  include Coordinate

  interface!

  sig { abstract.returns(Integer) }
  def z; end
end

class ThreeDLocation < T::Struct
  extend T::Sig
  
  include ThreeCoordinate
  
  # Will be complained by Sorbet because of missing interface
  const :x, Integer
end

class ThreeDCenter < T::Struct
  extend T::Sig

  include ThreeCoordinate

  sig { override.returns(Integer) }
  def x
    0
  end

  sig { override.returns(Integer) }
  def y
    0
  end

  sig { override.returns(Integer) }
  def z
    0
  end
end
```

Try out on [Sorbet Playground](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Amodule%20Coordinate%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AHelpers%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20interface!%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20abstract.returns%28Integer%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20x%3B%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20abstract.returns%28Integer%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20y%3B%20end%0Aend%0A%0Amodule%20ThreeCoordinate%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3AHelpers%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20include%20Coordinate%0A%0A%20%20interface!%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20abstract.returns%28Integer%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20z%3B%20end%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20ThreeDLocation%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%20%20%0A%20%20include%20ThreeCoordinate%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%23%20Will%20be%20complained%20by%20Sorbet%20because%20of%20missing%20interface%0A%20%20const%20%3Ax%2C%20Integer%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20ThreeDCenter%20%3C%20T%3A%3AStruct%0A%20%20extend%20T%3A%3ASig%0A%0A%20%20include%20ThreeCoordinate%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20override.returns%28Integer%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20x%0A%20%20%20%200%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20override.returns%28Integer%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20y%0A%20%20%20%200%0A%20%20end%0A%0A%20%20sig%20%7B%20override.returns%28Integer%29%20%7D%0A%20%20def%20z%0A%20%20%20%200%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A) to see how Sorbet static checks help ensure the typing.

Although there might be some repetitions in the codes, we have achieved the goal that classes implementing `ThreeCoordinate` is guaranteed to have the interface of `Coordinate` as well.

Also, using this approach, the implementation is more flexible. We can also implement something like `ThreeDCenter` above without being tied down to using Struct properties only.